# Graph Theory and Complements

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple undirected graph G = (V, E), we define the complement of G as $G^c$ = (V, $E^c$), where $E^c$ = {(u, v) : u, v ∈ V, u ≠ v, and (u, v) ∉ E}. In other words, $G^c$ is the graph containing exactly those edges that are not in G. 
Prove: max(|E|, $|E^c|$) ≥ n(n − 1)/4, where n is the number of vertices in G.

Comment: Yeah, well, that is an easy one-liner if you know what to do. So I assume that you do not, in which case it might help if you give your own ideas and approaches and tell where you get stuck.

Comment: Hint: If $x+y\ge n(n-1)/2$ then $\max(x,y)\ge n(n-1)/4.$

Comment: Been thinking about this and I have no clue---I think I am making this harder than it needs to be, especially if it is only one line

Answer (score 2):

Since $|E|+|E^C|=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, the maximum of them is greater than half of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.